Enable communication between two servers on local machine
I want to send an HTTP request from a server to a flask app, both running on my local machine.
I'm sending the http request as:
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://192.168.1.56:5000/api/forward-file", form);
I've used telnet command to check for connection on the flask app at
telnet 192.168.1.56 5000

I've even added a firewall rule to allow the connection.
After sending the request, the flask app prints on console the following error:
"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
ERROR:websocket:[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it - goodbye".

I'm sure that IP and Port are correct because flask prints:
* Running on http://192.168.1.56:5000"
And the controller on the Flask app is at /api/forward-file because of these settings @file_blueprint.route('/forward-file', methods=['POST']) on the flask controller and app.register_blueprint(file_blueprint, url_prefix='/api')

Show us the exact commands you use to start both services.

"actively refused it" means the server is not listening on the port. Maybe the flask app crashed after you tested it with telnet.

@JohnGordon The first server is an asp .net core app so just "dotnet build" while regarding the Flask app it was "python3 run.py" (run from PyCharm tho).
I'm new to Flask, so please if you need a specific information tell me.

@Barmar but even the Flask app prints it in the console; if it had crashed before I would have expected to see nothing printed in it or just a simple error while the full output is "* Serving Flask app 'app'

Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Running on http://192.168.1.56:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
Restarting with stat
Debugger is active!
Debugger PIN: 546-843-066"


if it is local connection then maybe check 127.0.0.1. You may also try with port 80 because some systems may block non-standard ports.

Do you see the server listening when you do netstat -an after the error happens?

Solved! The connection was refused by Flask because, when the controller was hit, it tried to instantiate a client to send an HTTP request. The problem was that this client lied into a container that wasn't up so turning on the external container fixed it.
